# Set value in XElement - do I really have to start from the root?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

The following works for me:

```
Xdoc.Element("session")
    .Element("immediate")
    .Element("pivot")
    .Element("axes")
    .Element("axis")
    .Element("attribute")
    .Element("selection")
    .Attribute("value")
    .SetValue("New_Value");
```

Do I really need to start at the top of the document? I know I can use descendants but then I cant reference the element?

Whats the correct way to do this? In XPath I would have done something similar to

```
/*/*/*/*etc
```

Comment: what is the "correct" way or both much of a muchness?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
var el = XElement.Parse("<session><immediate><pivot><axes><attribute><selection a=\"b\"/></attribute></axes></pivot></immediate></session>");
var sel = el.XPathSelectElement("immediate/pivot/axes/attribute/selection");
sel.SetAttributeValue("value","new_value");
```

? Note this needs:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Note that if this is rooted by a *document* you can use `/`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<session><immediate><pivot><axes><attribute><selection a=\"b\"/></attribute></axes></pivot></immediate></session>");
var sel = doc.XPathSelectElement("/session/immediate/pivot/axes/attribute/selection");
```

Another way would just be to look for `.Descendants("selection")`, but xpath is generally more flexible.